# Java Inter Process communication and Inter Thread communication?

Tags: java, multithreading

What is the difference between a Thread and a Process in the Java context?
How is inter-Process communication and inter-Thread communication achieved in Java?
Please point me at some real life examples.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The fundamental difference is that threads live in the same address spaces, but processes live in the different address spaces.  This means that inter-thread communication is about passing references to objects, and changing shared objects, but processes is about passing serialized copies of objects.

In practice, Java interthread communication can be implemented as plain Java method calls on shared object with appropriate synchronization thrown in.  Alternatively, you can use the new concurrency classes to hide some of the nitty-gritty (and error prone) synchronization issues.

By contrast, Java interprocess communication is based at the lowest level on turning state, requests, etc into sequences of bytes that can be sent as messages or as a stream to another Java process.  You can do this work yourself, or you can use a variety of "middleware" technologies of various levels of complexity to abstract away the implementation details.  Technologies that may be used include, Java object serialization, XML, JSON, RMI, CORBA, SOAP / "web services", message queing, and so on.

At a practical level, interthread communication is many orders of magnitude faster than interprocess communication, and allows you to do many things a lot more simply.  But the downside is that everything has to live in the same JVM, so there are potential scalability issues, security issues, robustness issues and so on.

Answer (score 6):

A thread can access memory inside a process, even memory that could be manipulated by another thread within the same process.  Since all threads are internal to the same running process, they can communicate more quickly (because they don't need the operating system to referee).

A process cannot access memory inside another process, although you can communicate between processes through various means like:

1. Network packages.
2. Files
3. Pipes
4. Shared Memory
5. Semaphores
6. Corba messages
7. RPC calls

The important thing to remember with process to process communication is that the communication must be managed through the operating system, and like all things which require a middle man, that adds overhead.

On the downside, if a thread misbehaves, it does so within the running process, and odds are high it will be able to take down all the well behaving threads.  If a process misbehaves, it can't directly write into the memory of the other processes, and odds are that only the misbehaving process will die.

Answer (score 3):

Inter-Thread Communication = threads inside the same JVM talking to each other

Inter-Process Communication (IPC) = threads inside the same machine but running in different JVMs talking to each other

Threads inside the same JVM can use pipelining through lock-free queues to talk to each other with nanosecond latency.

Threads in different JVMs can use off-heap shared memory (usually acquired through the same memory-mapped file) to talk to each other with nanosecond latency.

Threads in different machines can use the network to talk to each other with microsecond latency.

For a complete explanation about lock-free queues and IPC you can check [CoralQueue](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/category/coralqueue/).

**Disclaimer**: I am one of the developers of CoralQueue.

Answer (score 2):

I like to think of a single instance of a JVM as a process. So, interprocess communication would be between instances of JVM's, for example, through sockets (message passing).

Threads in java implement Runnable and are contained within a JVM. They share data simply by passing references in the JVM around. Whenever threads share data you almost always need to protect the data so multiple threads don't clobber each other. There are many mechanisms for protection that all involve preventing multiple threads from entering critical sections of code.